# How can I access the parent's field in another class and change it?

Tags: java, parent-child, jtextfield, mouselistener, jcomponent

)) I'm new to Java, And I have such task:

- Create a text field component class. In the constructor, the default string must be set in the text field.
- When clicking on the field, this record should be erased.
- If  user has not entered anything, and the focus from the field has been lost, then
  the default string should be restored.
  I have 3 classes: Main, MyComponent (extends JTextField), MyListener (implements MouseListener).
  Thats my class MyComponent:

```
public class MyComponent extends JTextField {
    
    private int code;
    
    public MyComponent(String text, int code) {
        super(text);
        this.code = code;
        setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 30));
}
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    
}
```

That's my Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My programm");
        frame.setBounds(320, 80, 750, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyComponent enterName = new MyComponent("Default name", MyListener.ENTERNAME);
        enterName.addMouseListener(new MyListener());
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel labelName = new JLabel("Enter name: ");

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        panel.add(labelName, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
        panel.add(enterName, c);
             
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
```

and that's MyListener class:

```
public class MyListener implements MouseListener {
    
    final static public int ENTERNAME = 1;
    MyComponent enterName;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int code = ((MyComponent)e.getSource()).getCode();
        if (code == ENTERNAME) {
            System.out.println("Clicked on JTF"); // just to understand that MouseListener is working
             // here I need code which in String text from enterName will put "" instead of "Default name"
             }
    //...

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    } 

    }
```

As I understand I need to make the text in the JTextField "Default name" disappear when I click the mouse.
But I don't understan how should I do that.
I also don't understand how to make it so that if the cursor is not on the JTextField, the default text "Default name" is returned.

I tried Reflection in MyListener, but it didn't work out well. That's my attempt:

```
public class MyListener implements MouseListener {
    
    final static public int ENTERNAME = 1;
    MyComponent enterName = new MyComponent("Ivan", MyListener.ENTERNAME);
    Field field = enterName.getClass().getField("text");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int code = ((MyComponent)e.getSource()).getCode();
        if (code == ENTERNAME) field.set(enterName, (String) " ");
    }
```

**Dear Professionals, please help me! :)**

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler than that. The class has public methods [setText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)) and [getText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()) to set/get the text. See this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html).

You **dont't need reflection here**, it's completely overkill and if you actually did need it, it would be a sign you were trying to do something the developers of JTextField didn't intend you to do.

It's just:

```
myComponent.setText("my awesome text");
```

My advice is that you forget you ever heard about Reflection until you are no longer "new to Java". 99% of the time you will not need it, and the 1% where you do, you should be knowing what you are doing.

In fact, that class **does not even have** an attribute `text`. Here is what setText [actually does](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent-source.html):

```
1377:   public void setText(String text)
1378:   {
1379:     try
1380:       {
1381:         if (doc instanceof AbstractDocument)
1382:           ((AbstractDocument) doc).replace(0, doc.getLength(), text, null);
1383:         else
1384:           {
1385:             doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());
1386:             doc.insertString(0, text, null);
1387:           }
1388:       }
1389:     catch (BadLocationException e)
1390:       {
1391:         // This can never happen.
1392:         throw (InternalError) new InternalError().initCause(e);
1393:       }
1394:   }
```

Comment: Hello! I don't exactly understand what to do. 

When I put in MyListener class: ' enterName.setText(" ") ;  
* without determining it in MyComponent, it tells me: 

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pkg6.pkg14.ex9.MyComponent.setText(String)" because "this.enterName" is null. 

But when I try to write your code from 1377 to 1394 with my names, IDE highlights almost everything to me in red. Can you explain me please more exactly what I should do ?

Comment: @Arina Store a reference to enterName in your MyListener. In your main method, pass enterName to the MyListener constructor and store it there as an attribute. It's null because it's never assigned.